# Double scrollbar when implementing parallax scrolling effect

Tags: html, css

I tried implementing a parallax scrolling effect to my website. And now when I put in some content and a footer I get two scrollbars, which is very annoying and I'd like some help on how to fix it so there's only one scrollbar. I'm implementing some bootstrap in my site, maybe that caused some problem? I linked a codepen with all the html, CSS and js.

https://codepen.io/vancee/pen/JjmWQpp

Html of the parallax scrolling, content and footer which seems to be what's causing the trouble:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
}

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}

.background {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.foreground {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
}

.background,
.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.title {
  font-size: 7rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--black-color);
}

section {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--body-bg-color);
  color: var(--white-color);
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
      <div class="parallax">
        <img src="https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2022/10/10/Kem93m.png" class="background" />
        <img src="https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2022/10/10/KemO9N.png" class="foreground" />
        <h1 class="title">Welcome!</h1>
      </div>
      <section>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse facilis unde illo neque at hic
        quisquam, nulla consectetur, itaque maxime sit iusto aliquam culpa reiciendis eaque
        recusandae vitae modi, animi expedita perferendis inventore. Culpa incidunt odit dicta
        quibusdam ullam facilis eum magnam, consectetur voluptates praesentium, pariatur eos nihil!
        Natus in, autem aut facere repellat eveniet commodi illo ullam hic fugit deserunt explicabo
        esse atque reprehenderit optio, dicta suscipit sed! Porro fugiat numquam vel magni, iure
        provident consequuntur velit ut quia itaque repudiandae molestiae, nobis sequi incidunt
        autem! Cum impedit accusamus laboriosam eaque necessitatibus consectetur incidunt a
        exercitationem molestias doloribus tenetur amet, ullam at repudiandae, quos reprehenderit
        adipisci assumenda dolor enim voluptas natus! Assumenda praesentium voluptate culpa quidem
        quasi impedit unde incidunt odit velit, dolore officiis distinctio, fugit, optio sed. Quos
        nesciunt eius reprehenderit ipsa consectetur tempora, fugiat provident corporis perspiciatis
        veritatis totam temporibus voluptates soluta vitae mollitia molestias reiciendis expedita
        doloribus est. Maxime et fugit expedita id sed cumque harum dignissimos aperiam voluptatum
        quos obcaecati illo tempore consectetur, sunt perferendis eius aliquid soluta praesentium
        voluptatem assumenda ex fuga. Iusto, possimus? Dolores deleniti eaque, aperiam consequuntur
        odit culpa, architecto, quas veniam provident inventore eius. Laboriosam in reprehenderit
        quidem? Officiis illum molestiae, praesentium velit, illo debitis quasi fuga laborum
        veritatis necessitatibus fugiat cupiditate! Quia animi provident maxime numquam porro
        itaque! Provident, rerum. Aliquid cum quo ducimus ad? Repellat nihil, saepe beatae rerum
        sint eveniet voluptate officiis velit autem officia tempore deserunt sequi quod quae culpa
        sed. Reprehenderit eveniet ipsum nihil ipsam quam facilis, possimus modi placeat ratione
        soluta voluptate obcaecati error minima enim, fugiat quaerat architecto, iure dignissimos a
        eum quidem eos at fuga. Consectetur, quisquam at reprehenderit in exercitationem inventore
        incidunt dolorum quos adipisci labore? Fugiat facilis ipsum minus, officiis eos modi sequi
        distinctio pariatur reprehenderit accusantium labore obcaecati, recusandae saepe?
      </section>
 </main>
<footer class="text-center text-white">
      <div class="container">
        <section class="mt-5">
          <div class="row text-center d-flex justify-content-center pt-5">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                <a href="#!" class="text-white">Hem</a>
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                <a href="#!" class="text-white">Länk 1</a>
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                <a href="#!" class="text-white">Länk 2</a>
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                <a href="#!" class="text-white">Länk 3</a>
              </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <hr class="my-5" />
        <section>
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8 mb-4">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt distinctio earum
                repellat quaerat voluptatibus placeat nam, commodi optio pariatur est quia magnam
                eum harum corrupti dicta, aliquam sequi voluptate quas.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
</footer>
```

I tried using overflow: hidden; on the body, html and some elements I thought may cause trouble but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: `body { overflow: hidden; }` as last line in the CSS worked for me... (Windows Desktop, Firefox).

Comment: @RenevanderLende then my footer gets removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See working version here:
https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/qBJmWOd

1. Set `<body>` to always be `overflow: hidden`, which makes sense if you're going to handle scrolling within an inner wrapper.
2. Re-structured the HTML such that `.wrapper` wraps the hero (parallax section), `<main>` and `<footer>`. When I did all this, everything else you did seems to work fine.

---

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>parallax composition: title + images</header>
    <main>content</main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

---

**Side note:** One could argue the hero (parallax section) is technically a header for your content, so it would best be a `<header>` element; this is "content-level" context. This of course has nothing to do with your earlier `<header>` element wrapping your top `<nav>` (which is "page-level" context). It's fine having multiple occurrences of `<header>` in a given webpage.